# How should I write destructor for this class in C++?

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a class that has this kind of structure:

```
class myClass(){
  public:
    myClass(){//empty constructor}
    
    void insertRecursively(string word) {
        myClass* node = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (node->map.find(word.at(i)) == node->map.end()) {
                node->map[word.at(i)] = new myClass();
            }
            node = node->map[word.at(i)];
        }
        node->isEnd = true;
    }

  
  private:
    unordered_map<char, myClass*> map = {};
    bool isEnd = false;
}
```

I tried write destructor in this way but it gives me error 'std::bad_alloc':

```
~myClass() {
    clear(map);
}

void clear(unordered_map<char, myClass*> map) {
    for (auto& pair : map) {
        if (pair.second != nullptr) {
            clear(pair.second->map);
        }
        delete pair.second;
    }
}
```

From what I known so far, I allocated memory on heap by using new keyword, so I should create destructor for myClass. I need to do this recursively because map contains pointers to other myClass pointers.

I've researched several hours and still cannot figure it out.
Can anyone help me to spot the problem that will cause 'std::bad_alloc' ?

My entire code:

```
class Trie {
public:
    Trie() {
    }

    void insert(string word) {
        Trie* node = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (node->map.find(word.at(i)) == node->map.end()) {
                node->map[word.at(i)] = new Trie();
            }
            node = node->map[word.at(i)];
        }
        node->isEnd = true;
    }

    bool search(string word) {
        Trie* node = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            if (node->map.find(word.at(i)) == node->map.end()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                node = node->map[word.at(i)];
            }
        }
        return node->isEnd;
    }

    bool startsWith(string prefix) {
        Trie* node = this;
        for (int i = 0; i < prefix.length(); i++) {
            if (node->map.find(prefix.at(i)) == node->map.end()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                node = node->map[prefix.at(i)];
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    ~Trie() {
        clear(map);
    }

    void clear(unordered_map<char, Trie*> map) {
        for (auto& pair : map) {
            if (pair.second != nullptr) {
                clear(pair.second->map);
            }
            delete pair.second;
        }
    }

private:
    unordered_map<char, Trie*> map = {};
    bool isEnd = false;
};
```

Comment: You should use a smart pointer and then not worry about it.

Comment: Also replace `new myClass()` with `std::make_unique<myClass>()` since manual memory management is no fun.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I will use smart pointers next time.

Comment: The type of the map is incorrect here: `void clear(unordered_map<char, myClass> map)` You're missing a `*`.  The recursion is unnecessary since each instance of `MyClass` can clear its own map. `for (auto& pair : map) { delete pair.second; }`

Comment: Why use a pointer at all? There is no need for it and without all the memory management is already done for you.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Some indirection is required, since `unordered_map` is not guaranteed to work with incomplete value type (i.e. recursively). But that indirection should be in my opinion via `std::unique_ptr`, not a raw pointer.

Comment: @user17732522 Good point, hadn't considered that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I draw your attention to the following lines of code.

```
unordered_map<char, myClass*> map = {};
void clear(unordered_map<char, myClass> map)
```

Trimming a few characters...

```
unordered_map<char, myClass*> map
void clear(unordered_map<char, myClass> map)
```

Observe that you declared the local item map over char and myClass*, but you declared clear() as operating on a map over char and myClass, as opposed to a map over char and myClass*.

The * makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I've posted my complete code down below. Please refer to the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Either you start to use *smart pointers* or you need to bring up a concept of ownership for your `myClass` instances created with `new`.

The latter could be:

- Instances `a`of `myClass` are owned by another instance of `myClass` (lets call it `owner`) where `&a` appears in `owner.map` (You are doing this already).
- Whenever an instance `owner` becomes destroyed, it has to free all instances it (directly) owns:

```
~myClass() {
  for(const auto& pair : map){
    delete pair.second;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Trie::clear()` method deletes the same `Trie` twice.

```
~Trie() {
    clear(map);
}

void clear(unordered_map<char, Trie*> map) {
    for (auto& pair : map) {
        if (pair.second != nullptr) {
            clear(pair.second->map);
        }
        delete pair.second;
    }
}
```

The destructor `~Trie` calls `clear(pair.second->map)` and then calls `delete pair.second` which is the same as `clear(pair.second->map)` again since `delete` calls the destructor of the pointed-at data. Calling `clear()` twice on the same map means that the second call is trying to delete already deleted data, which causes the crash. Calling `delete` on a pointer does not change the value of the pointer, which is why the `nullptr` check does nothing.

Since the destructor calls `clear()`, the `clear()` method does not need to explicitly call itself recursively. Just delete the map pointers.

```
~Trie() {
    clear(map);
}

void clear(unordered_map<char, Trie*> map) {
    for (auto& pair : map) {
        delete pair.second;
    }
}
```

By the way, calling `delete nullptr` is fine since it is required to do nothing.